# Query is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to execute query using sequelize ORM but getting the error from mysql server.

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'user_recipe_item.ingredient' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

code -

```
await UserRecipeItem.findAll({
    where: {
      weekNumber: week,
      userId: user.id,
      recipeId: {
        [OP.in]: shoppingListRecipeList,
      },
    },
    attributes: [
      "ingredient",
      [Sequelize.fn("sum", Sequelize.col("quantity")), "quantityCount"],
    ],
    group: [Sequelize.fn("LOWER", Sequelize.col("ingredient"))],
    order: [["ingredient", "desc"]],
  });
```

and generated query from sequelize

```sql
SELECT `ingredient`, sum(`quantity`) AS `quantityCount` 
FROM `user_recipe_item` AS `user_recipe_item` 
WHERE `user_recipe_item`.`weekNumber` = '5' 
  AND `user_recipe_item`.`userId` = '3f0bb77c-bcac-49f4-a841-cf8ec9ffb9f0' 
  AND `user_recipe_item`.`recipeId` IN ('0e63cc1e-cfc4-4b0b-9ffe-927576c00b8a', '6b20df48-5844-440a-b8c4-fe33b6295a85', 'ebf8a108-7474-43a4-9cb0-ef1d4d23e019', 'a98fa8df-f527-43ac-a81f-95711b8689e7') 
GROUP BY LOWER(`ingredient`) 
ORDER BY `user_recipe_item`.`ingredient` DESC;
```

Comment: If you group by ```LOWER(`ingredient`)``` then you must use the same expression in the output list, not single `ingredient`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.